# langchain installtion issue: retrievers subpackge not installing, llms.bedrok does appear neither ConversationRetrievalChain from langchain.chains

Tags: python-3.x, langchain, large-language-model, amazon-kendra

After I install langchain with pip install I can not find the following sub-packages/objects:

- retrievers subpackage not installing and directory langchain/retrievers not appearing at all
- AmazonKendraRetriever does no appear of ourse
- bedrock does not appear inside directory langchain/llms neither in **init**
- ConversationLRetrievalChain does not appear under langchain/chains or **init**

I tried  in requirements.txt the below combinations, but none solved the issue

***requirements.txt***

```
langchain
langchain[all]
langchain.retrievers
```

I'm pining a ***--python-version 311*** and also ***--platform manylinux1X86_64*** to pip install to have no issues with pydantic.

How to solve this issue ??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that limiting the installation as I did above will always left outside libraries that have no wheels. So this method should not be used unless you are aware that all subpackges do have wheels. Use a contanarized lambda layer instead was the solution

Answer (score 1):

Could you try below steps.

Create a virtual environment using the command

```
 python -m venv my_venv_name
```

Activate the virtual environment by executing source

```
 my_venv_name/bin/activate
```

PIP install libraries

```
pip install langchain
pip install """Other required libraries like OpenAI etc..
```

You should now successfully able to import

```
 from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
 from langchain.chains import LLMChain, ConversationChain
 from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
 from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
 from langchain.prompts.chat import (
    ChatPromptTemplate,
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate,
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a virtual environment solved the issue as mentioned by ZKS
use my_venv_name/scripts/activate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).